# How to name information that has to be provided to someone vs by someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In web app user interface I have a screen for a "task".
On this screen, a user can see a form with fields.
For each field user can indicate *one of two* options:

1. This field contains information that is required in order for the user to complete the task. E.g., a field named "Salary" may be required to complete the task "Prepare job offer email". And this field should be filled in by the other user, as part of working on another task "Provide compensation details for job offer".
2. This field is required to be filled in by the user to mark the task as completed. That is for data that would be needed by someone else on next steps.

I am trying to find a short way of naming these two options.
Option (2) is very common and is usually named as "required field" or "mandatory field". How can I name option (1)?

Comment: You say, "[T]his field is required to be filled in *by someone else on a previous step.*" Sorry for being dense, but I do not quite understand. Can you put this in other words (or, if you prefer, if the quoted clause is inessential to the question, can you ask the question without the clause)?

Comment: Sure, will try to rephrase now

Comment: @thb : Any better now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand your problem much better than I do, so here are a few options: *dependent field; transferred field; transferrent field; referent field; extracted field; awaited field; prerequisite field; postrequisite field; corequisite field.* To the extent to which I understand your problem, at your discretion, I suggest first investigating *corequisite field.* The prefix and stem of *corequisite* are both Latin, so this word may carry with minimal translation to all Western languages. A thing is *corequisite* if it is *separately required at the same time.*

Plain *requisite* just means "required." Prepending the *co-,* which as you know means "with" or "along with," makes it "separately required."

However, if it is required *before,* then you must prefer *prerequisite.* If *after,* than *postrequisite.* *Corequisite* only works if the requirement is at the same time.

Good luck.